# Cambiar estilo de un input type="file"

Tags: angularjs, css3, ionic

Quiero saber si es posible cambiarle el estilo por defecto que aparece al colocar un `<input type="file" />` en nuestra página. Aquí dejo una captura de pantalla.

[image: Guardar imagen en localstorage]

La imagen anterior es una captura de pantalla de mi tablet, donde guardo la ruta de la imagen para luego mostrarla en la vista.

Quisiera quitar el input de la manera por defecto que aparece, y colocarlo en la esquina superior derecha y que solo aparezca el boton estilo clear button de ionic, tal cual edite la imagen.

Link del codigo: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKbjYP)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto: http://codepen.io/tibomahe/pen/qZbGEw??

Comment: ayuda :c https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94176/login-con-facebook-y-ionic-no-pasa-parametros-a-la-otra-pantalla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que quieres es bastante difícil de lograr y puedes ver un ejemplo de como hacerlo en el siquiente link

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Yo he logrado lo mismo sin mucha dificultad ocultando el input de tipo file y usando un botón común y corriente que puedes estilar como gustes

Aquí te dejo una directiva que puedes usar en la que sólo tienes que cambiar el elemento `button` a lo que quieres usar en su lugar.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('pickFile', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: 
        '<button class="button">Pick</button>' +
        '<input type="file" style="display: none !important">',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        var input = $element.find('input');
        var button = $element.find('button');

        var evtHandler = function() {
          input[0].click();
        };

        button.on('click', evtHandler)
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <pick-file></pick-file>
</div>
```

Esto es el ejemplo más sencillo posible, como estás usando ionic puedes usar las [clases de estilo](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#buttons) de este o las tuyas propias para diseñar los botones.

Algo como

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round"></button>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo completo

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
  .directive('pickFile', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round pull-right">' +
        '<input type="file" style="display: none !important">' +
        '</button>',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        var input = $element.find('input');
        var button = $element.find('button');

        var evtHandler = function() {
          input[0].click();
        };

        button.on('click', evtHandler)
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
    <pick-file></pick-file>
    <h1 class="title">Perfil estudiante</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, voy a probar solo copiando lo que necesito para funcionar pegando el boton y el input dentro del header

Comment: me sale este error l tratar de hacerlo de la forma normal
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- perfilEstudiante`

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Quizas copiaste mal el código o estás tratando de ponerlo en un controller. Fijate que lo que te puse fue una directiva por lo que $element no es un inyectable sino uno de los parámetros de la función link.

Comment: Si eso hice, las tima que no este trabajando con directivas

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Recuerda que en angular los componentes reutilizables **siempre** son directivas por lo que te recomiendo que modifiques el código que te puse para adaptarlo a tus necesidades en lugar de usarlo en un controller.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept, voy a aprender directivas de una vez, o a tratar de ver como le hago, ya que sirve este ejemplo, hare lo posible por hacerlo funcionar, gracias de nuevo

Comment: no quise robarte la respuesta :P

Comment: @rnd realmente no me molesta que intentes ayudar al OP, lo que me parece incorrecto es que uses mi respuesta para agregar solo un poco de código y quedarte con el crédito de la respuesta aceptada. Eso lo podría haber arreglado yo mismo siempre y cuando el OP modificara su pregunta agregando más información. En ningún momento se aclaró que es lo que es lo que se intentaba hacer. Ese es el problema de usar el chat para debatir el contenido de la pregunta. Cualquiera que la lea no va a entender cual es la mejora en tu respuesta.

Comment: No te enojes, solo quise ayudar. @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales lo mejor sería que le des la respuesta correcta a de devconcept. Saludos a todos.!! Y Buen codeo.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es colocando el input file con opacity "0" por encima de un div o span diseñado como botón o como quieras que se muestre. Para que así, al cliquear sobre el input file (que no se ve pero está y tiene las mismas dimensiones que el div con estilos), se abra la pestaña de selección de archivos. Es algo así como mostrar un diseño que no tiene funcionalidad, y la funcionalidad ( que la da el input file) va a estar "invisible" al usuario.

Nota: También podrías usar visibility hidden para ocultar al input

Comment: Voy a probar, y te digo como me fue

Comment: Buenísimo. Espero que logres los resultados esperados.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, cree un ejemplo super sencillo en Codepen. 
Solo con estilos Css podes hacer lo que te propones, espero que te sirva.

[Link Codepen - Ejemplo File Css](http://codepen.io/facundofernandez/pen/PNLGzO)

Comment: Muy bueno, voy a ver como aplico a mi proyecto

Answer (score 1):

A pedido del OP, He modificado la directiva creada por @devconcept, para que pueda integrarse al código que ya tiene de forma sencilla.

Una vez que seleccionas un archivo llama a un evento del controlador donde haces lo mismo que venias haciendo.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo completo en [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rnrneverdies/pen/qZvpJq).

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.recibido = function(file) {
       console.log(file); // aqui tienes el file
    }
    
  })
  .directive('pickFile', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
         onselected: "&"
      },
      template: '<button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round pull-right">' +
        '<input type="file" style="display: none !important">' +
        '</button>',
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        var input = $element.find('input');
        var button = $element.find('button');

        var evtHandler = function() {
          input[0].click();
        };

        button.on('click', evtHandler)
        input.on('change', function () {
          var file = input[0].files[0];
          $scope.onselected({ file: file });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
    <pick-file onselected="recibido(file)"></pick-file>
    <h1 class="title">Perfil estudiante</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ya funciona gracias maestro

Answer (score 0):

Ya te han dado varias soluciones por aquí, pero... ¿y usar ngCordova con Ionic? Hay un plugin para transferencia de archivos que te permite trasladar toda la lógica del `<input type="file">` a una función que tu mismo defines dentro de tu controlador, por lo que te da total libertad para crear un botón de subida de archivos.

Échale un ojo http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: Ok, lo revise un poco pero veo solo ara uso con internet, de igual forma le echare una mano.

Comment: No, el plugin se añade a `cordova.js` cuando compilas tu aplicación, de modo que funciona también offline.