# Native Storage Error, no muestra la siguiente pantalla - IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy tratando de implementar un login, el cual tiene 2 opciones de registro, una con tus datos que están en FB, y la otra ponerlos de forma manual.

En la primera forma, el usuario usa su cuenta de **facebook**, para obtener los datos correspondientes de este usuario nombre y correo, después este es direccionado a la siguiente vista o interfaz, donde deberá colocar un número telefónico, para luego colocar los datos en input's o cajas de texto.

En la segunda opción de registro, el usuario utiliza la opción **Registrar Ahora**, donde el usuario es llevado a la pagina anteriormente nombrada, pero en este caso, los input's están vacíos.

[image]
Mi error surge cuando le doy en la segunda opción, y me sale el siguiente error y no muestra la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que esta vacio **Entonces mi duda es la siguiente como le hago que cuando llegue vacio muestre la pantalla normal**

Quizas es error este en esta clase:

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
        console.log('Ya llegue');
        let env = this;
        return this.nativeStorage.getItem('user')
            .then(function (data) {
                env.user = {
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email
                };
                console.log(env.user);
                env.userReady = true;
                return true;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            });
    }
```

> Y este es mi html de mi pagina resgistro donde los 2 botones llegan:

```
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
    <img src="assets/logito.png">
    <br>
    <br>

    <ion-list *ngIf="userReady">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Nombres" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input clearInput type="number" placeholder="Teléfono">
            </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='checkmark-circle-outline'></ion-icon>
        registar
      </button>
</ion-content>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues ya miraste si esta retornando algo la peticion del login?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales como me fijo si me devuelve algo ya que defrente lo estoy corriendo en mi emulador ya que el plugin de fb no funciona en el navegador

Comment: Pues no se si sepas usar el `chrome://inspect`, si no avisame y te explico

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales una consulta mira, como hago para que cuando pase parametros por nativeStorage, no traiga nada me muestre la pantalla igual osea si me quiero registrar con fb el plugin jala el nombre y correo a la pantalla registro que espera 2 valores pero si hago click en registro normal osea para que el mismo ponga su nombre y correo me muestre la misma pantalla, actualmnte me sa un error al darle click en REGISTRAR AHORA ya que la otra pagina espera un correo e email y pues no le estoy mandando nada, como hago que cuando este null igual me abra esa pagina.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSgJR.gif mira este enlace cuando le doy en **Registrate ahora** me sale error pero el login con fb es normal :c

Comment: deja reviso, y quizas creo saber

Comment: puedes entrar aqui, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales te explico mejor mira si me conecto mediante fb en el nativestorage se guarda el nombre y el email y eso lo refleja en la otra pantalla pero cuando le doy en **Registrate ahora** no guarda nada en nativestorage es por eso, quiero hacer un if si en el nativeStorage no hay nada igual me deje pasar a la otra pantalla ahora se detiene xq dice que no hay datos y eso me genera el error :c

Comment: Lo que debes hacer, pienso yo es, que dependiendo de los parámetros saber si es un login manual como dices tu, o usando algún tipo de red social

Answer (score 2):

Estuve viendo el .gif y creo que lo que estás haciendo en redirigiendo a un mismo lugar con parámetros diferentes, como si quisieras acceder a un método una vez con los parámetros que espera y otra sin parámetros lo cual no estaría correcto.

En el plugin de facebook cuando completas el formulario envía la información que llenaste y luego llega al console.log("Ya llegué") con los valores que ingresaste.

De acuerdo a la documentación te está llegando un código 2 que quiere decir que no encuentra el item en este caso 'user'. 
Documentación codes: [error-codes](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage#error-codes)

En el registrar ahora debes validar que si venga algo, si no manda los valores vacíos a la otra ventana o redirige a una ventana diferente.

Comment: eso necesito validar si no hay nada mandar vacios a la otra pagina, aiuda :c

Comment: Es con gusto  :)

Comment: Actulamente en el **Registrarte ahora!** solo lo redirecciono con *[navPush]="registroNPage">*

Comment: Como mando valores vacios :c

Comment: Yo supondría que dependiendo de como estés manejando el código, si en el function (error){..} si estás redirigiendo o asignas a las variables "" campos vacías al env.user ya que no tienes data

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/
Pero recuerda inicializarlo para no tener errores https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121961/ionic-2-exception-no-provider-for-navcontroller

Comment: link muerto :c @Dwan

Comment: Que extraño a mi ambos me abren :s